# (Azure DevOps Testplans) Is it possible to associate an automated Test to a testcase without Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, automated-tests

My Goal is to trigger my testcafe-test via the test case and not with the pipeline. on the microsoft docs they say i need visual studio, but is it possible to link my test to a test case without it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kHB0.png)

Comment: You can use the REST APIs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (Azure DevOps Testplans) Is it possible to associate an automated Test to a testcase without Visual Studio?

You could use REST API to do this [Work Items - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0):

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=6.0
```

Content-Type: `application/json-patch+json`

Body:

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestName",
    "value": "[namespace.classname.methodname (e.g. UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod2)]"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestStorage",
    "value": "[assembly name(e.g. unittestproject1.dll)"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestId",
    "value": "[guid id]"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestType",
    "value": "Unit Test"
  },
   {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomationStatus",
    "value": "Automated"
  }
]
```

Comment: My coding skills are not the best. Do i put this code directly into my project (create a new JSON file there?) or put it into my package.json?

Comment: @easy651, I am afraid not, we need to create a pipeline with inline powershell task to invoke the REST API scripts to associate an automated Test to a testcase. like https://abhijitjana.net/2020/04/11/exploring-azure-devops-apis/. But this requires at least a little bit of code ability.

Comment: @easy651, If you do not want use REST API, I am afraid we have to use the visual Studio instead.

Comment: Alright i will try it with the REST API. ty.  problem with visual studio is that my testcafe tests are not shows in the the explorer, so i cant associate them. @leo Liu-MSFT

Comment: @easy651, That`s be ok, if you get any issue when you use the REST API, welcome to open a new thread with details scripts you have tried and the error log in the question.